# pre populated fields

Tags: php, html

I have a contact.php form on my site that can be accessed form two sources. What I would like to happen is, when someone accesses the form from the footer menu they get a blank form with all fields open for them to enter data. and when someone accesses the contact form from one of our ads, the subject line is pre populated with the item id and name. could someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

The link from footer menu must be href="contact.php" , while that from ad must be href="contact.php?subject=sub". So in contact.php, use `$_GET['subject']` to fetch the subject value and if it is not null, assign it to the subject field value using

```
<input type="text" name="subjectfield" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['subject']){ echo $_GET['subject'];}?>">
```

Comment: depending on php setting you might get notice for undefined variable, better to check fisrt